# Insert an Image to a Button in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have the following piece of XAML that add an image in a Button. The XAML works fine:

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="Images/reset.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I tried to convert the above XAML to C# but didn't get it to work

```
Button btn = new Button();

Grid imgGrid = new Grid();
imgGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
imgGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ReighGaugeSoftware1;component/Images/config.png"));
img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
imgGrid.Children.Add(img);
Grid.SetRow(img, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(img, 0);

btn.Content = imgGrid;
```

It was a straight-forward conversion, but the debugging throws me a "XamlParseException was unhandled" which I cannot relate to my code. Can anyone point out where it went wrong?

Comment: @Greg that's what I thought. I commanded out the code and it does NOT occurs. It occurs when the code is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exception being thrown in your code but it's obscured by the XamlParseException.  My guess is that the image path is wrong.

In Visual Studio, key Ctrl-Alt-E to bring up the Exceptions window, then ensure that Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked in both columns, then run your code.

Execution will break at the line of code where the error is occurring, it should be easy enough to fix from there (if not, post the Exception text).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only think that is different is the Uri, so i suspect there might be something wrong with it, see this [page on pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).